# Use snapshot library when developing a web app in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven

I develop a web application using eclipse, maven and tomcat container. My web app uses snapshot version of a Java library that I also work on. In eclipse both projects (web app and the library) are open. The library is a regular Maven/Java project, and the web app is a Dynamic Web Application.

The problem is that eclipse under `Maven Dependencies` displays the library project as open, and not the jar files, so when I want to debug the web app the jar of that library is not copied into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of tomcat. If I use a release version of the library, eclipse displays the jar file and is copied into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of tomcat.

To solve that problem I have to close the library project and it works as expected (jar copied into tomcat). Is there a way to include an open project into a dynamic web app when debugging it with tomcat under eclipse?

.classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it works in web projects but

```
<project> -> context menu -> Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution
```

will stop the *m2eclipse* plugin to resolve dependencies in the workspace (by checking open projects). The dependencies will be requested from the (local) repository instead. Thus you have to `install` your library project if you want a new version to be referenced by your web project.